# @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) in HSQL doesn't auto generate primary key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

My env is  Spring 4.0.5, hibernate 4.3.6, hsql 2.3.2. In production it will connect to mysql.

The original entity class annotate the auto_increment primary key column like this

```
@Id
@Column(name = "sid", nullable = true)
private Long sid;
```

And then I try to correct it to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "sid", nullable = false)
private Long sid;
```

But in test environment, I use `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` with `config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");` to export schema, but I can't persist this class, since it complains it violate NOT NULL constraint.

However when I did the search, all articles said GenerationType.IDENTITY is supported by MySql and HSQLDB, is there other reason that this may fail?

========== to generate schema ============

```
private void generateSchema() {
    final SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(getConfig());
    export.setDelimiter(";");
    export.create(true, true);
}

private Configuration getConfig() {
    final Configuration config = new Configuration();

    config.addAnnotatedClass(A.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(B.class);
            ...

    config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", getUrl());
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "SA");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    return config;
}
```

===============update stacktrace===========

```
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        taxo_dim
        (region_id, taxonomy_name)
    values
        (?, ?)
  3794 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: -10, SQLState: 23502
  3794 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10192 table: TAXO_DIM column: SID
  3796 [main] ERROR com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO  - Unable to create Object. com.model.Taxonomy@56dfab87
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.persist(Unknown Source)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO.create(AbstractAwrDAO.java:30)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e51ea1.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
  at com.dao.TaxonomyDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b976ae4.create(<generated>)
  at com.dao.RequestDataDAOTest.testCreate(RequestDataDAOTest.java:104)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
  at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
  at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
  ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10192 table: TAXO_DIM column: SID
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
  ... 67 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10192 table: TAXO_DIM column: SID
  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
  ... 70 more
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.persist(Unknown Source)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO.create(AbstractAwrDAO.java:30)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e51ea1.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
  at com.dao.TaxonomyDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b976ae4.create(<generated>)
  at com.dao.RequestDataDAOTest.testCreate(RequestDataDAOTest.java:104)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
  at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
  at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
  ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10192 table: TAXO_DIM column: SID
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
  ... 67 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10192 table: TAXO_DIM column: SID
  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
  ... 70 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.04 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.dao.RequestDataDAOTest
testCreate(com.dao.RequestDataDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 0.036 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.yahoo.aiy.exception.AiyException: Unable to create Object. com.model.Taxonomy@56dfab87
  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
  at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
  at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.persist(Unknown Source)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO.create(AbstractAwrDAO.java:30)
  at com.dao.AbstractAwrDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e51ea1.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
  at com.dao.TaxonomyDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b976ae4.create(<generated>)
  at com.dao.RequestDataDAOTest.testCreate(RequestDataDAOTest.java:104)
```

=========== looks like the problem ================

================ message while generating schema =======

```
create table taxo_dim (
    sid bigint not null,
    region_id integer not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (sid)
)
```

It only has not null constraint but not anything related to auto increment. However I don't know why GenerateType.IDENTITY doesn't do anything about it. This table will not join with others, so there is no @OneToMany or others in this class

Comment: What is failing, and how is it failing? Post the relevant code and the stack trace. Show us how you defined the associated table.

Comment: Is there another `nullable = false` attribute?. Also you could get rid of the @Column annotation.

Comment: @lametaweb: no there is only one nullable = false for that column.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the reason.

We have 2 classes reference to the same table, each class implements the same interface with different implementation as a workaround for our internal infrastructure requirement.

I modify generation strategy in one but didn't notice there is another, and Hibernate is always creating table with the latter configuration.